# Compare two columns in one sheet against two columns in a second sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My first sheet has two columns. They are a list of Users (many duplicates) and their corresponding search ID (a 9 digit number)

My second sheet has two columns as well. A list of Users (many duplicates) and their corresponding search IDs (1-100 IDs of 9 digit numbers separated by commas [ex: 123456789, 113456789, etc...)

Is there a way two compare the two lists by the other two lists? Essentially I'd like to see if the user with an ID in sheet one has a match in sheet two amongst the other IDs. So I want to match not only the Users, but the ID as well from sheet one if it's also found amongst the lists in sheet two.

I've used 
=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(D2,Searches!$C$1:$C$2000),Searches!$C$1:$C$2000)),"NOT FOUND",MATCH("*"&D2&"*",Searches!$C$1:$C$2000,0))

This finds me the user in sheet two and returns which row they are in. However they could be in multiple rows but I'm only getting back one row. How do I get all the rows that it is in?

Comment: You could use a for loop to loop through both

Comment: Do the IDs also have duplicates??? (Why not searching only for the ID if it's unique?)

Comment: You should use an Instr(ID sheet 2, ID sheet 1) to see if it's among the several IDs when you compare with a loop.

Comment: The first sheet is Users and what ID was purchased. The second sheet is Users and what IDs were searched. That's why I want to see what Users searched, and if the purchases were related to searches or not.

Comment: You could sort both sheets, then apply an AutoFilter for each user on sheet 2. It would be easier if you could provide a few sample rows from both sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to see something like:

- for each unique user: all purchases
- for each unique user: all searches

You can add two pivot tables (insert > pivot table, preferrably in a new sheet). One taking the data of the first sheet, the other taking the data of the second sheet.

So, you will be presented a sidebar where you can add the fields (user and purchase for the first sheet, user and search for the second sheet).

All you have to do is to drag and drop the `user` field to the `row labels`, and then drag the `purchase` field **also** to the `row labels`.

Do this for both pivot tables (one with user/purchase and the other with user/search)

You will have two tables telling all the purchases for a user (no duplicates) and all the searches for a user (no duplicates).

Addtitionally, you can add other fields to the `values` box and see the amount of searches and purchases, things like that.